# Total Count with eloquent

Tags: laravel-7, eloquent-relationship

I have a two table users and orders . i want to get users with Total Orders Count. How can I do this with eloquent?

Here is my query

```
User::with('orders')->where('status','active')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withCount` for this.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

```
User::withCount('orders')->where('status','active')->get();
```